# Defining a curve from three points

Tags: java, algorithm, interpolation

I have a class with three arbitrary `float` values stored in it. Let's call them A B and C. The class has a method that will take an input float in the range of -1 to +1 and then return a value based on the input.

calling the method with value -1 will result in the value of A, calling it with 0 will result in B, calling it with 1 will result in C. The question now is, how can i interpolate an output for everything in between?

I was thinking of an imaginary curve/spline based on three points defined as  -1xA 0xB and 1xC. With a function that can plot this curve, providing output for any float in the range can be calculated.

NB:

- The exact form of the curve isn't that important, but it must never provide an output higher than the highest of A B or C, nor can it provide an output lower than A, B, or C. As I need to test it to see what works best, I cannot say if the curve has to be smooth at all.
- There is no restriction as to which of the stored float values is higher or lower. Two of them might even be the same.
- At first i was thinking of using the three points to define a circle, however this could result in output values outside of the range of A B and C

Normally I would post some code here to illustrate what i have so far, but as I don't really know how to attack this problem I do not see any point in posting just an empty function definition.

PS:

If someone is curious why, I am using input from a controller to define the angle of a joint, so the output value will never be outside the range of -180 to +180

Comment: if the form of the interpolation curve isn't important, can you just create a piecewise linear function with the three points?

Comment: just to clarify, A B and C are 1 dimensional points correct?

Comment: @Ben I was thinking of it, yes, but as stated above, I am not sure what works best in the end, so I would prefer to have a method for a somewhat smooth result as well. Also, since A < B < C is NOT the case, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve that either.

Comment: hmm, if the points are one dimensional, a linear approach is "smooth" at all?

Comment: It seems that the three "points" are two-dimensional: the first is at (-1, A), the second is at (0, B), and the third is at (1, C).

Comment: @Jarmund you're going to have to give more specifications if you want a "smooth" curve. I'll give a piecewise linear solution that is continuous so that you don't have to worry about whether A < B < C or whatever.

Comment: @ben Any kind of smooth curve that doesn't result in pointy mountaintops or narrow pits

Comment: You could model the points around a quadratic Bézier curve?

Comment: @sbat From what I've understood of quadratic bézier curves, it will never actially touch upon the middle point, which is need this function to do. As mentioned, an input of 0 should give the exact value of B. Or did I misunderstand QBCs?

Comment: Pick the point where the mid area between two points has the slope of zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is a piece-wise linear function as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24834167/850781).

However, a comment says "Any kind of smooth curve that doesn't result in pointy mountaintops or narrow pits".

The second simplest answer is to use the unique parabola which goes through the 3 points (quadratic interpolation) but that violates the requirement that all the values must be between `min(A,B,C)` and `max(A,B,C)`.

So we are stuck with the 3rd simplest answer: use a piece-wise quadratic function with 0 derivative at 0:

```
f(x) = B + (C-B) * x^2  when x is in [0,1]
       B + (A-B) * x^2  when x is in [-1,0]
```

Comment: How does this translate to Java?

Comment: @Jarmund Ternary operator, or just an if... this function is simple enough

Comment: In fact, you could use a simple parabola for when A < B < C, and piece wise interpolation with any function that is monotonic on (0;1) and has deriv 0 at 0. But really, OP has to actually choose a function that has the best characteristics for them.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a piecewise linear function using the three points (-1, A), (0, B), (1, C)

```
f(x) = (B-A)(x+1)+A if x in [-1, 0)
     = (C-B)x+B if x in [0, 1]
```

(and if someone knows TeX and want to make that pretty by all means)...

there are some pretty fancy interpolation methods for smooth functions, by making f(x) differentiable at x = B, but it's been a while since my numerical analysis class...

Answer (score 1):

Piecewise linear interpolation respects the constraints but is only C0 continuous.

You can achieve C1 continuity with piecewise parabolic interpolation (`y = A x(x-1)/2 + B (x+1)(1-x) + C x(x+1)/2`), but you must ensure that the two pieces are monotonous (no maximum, except possibly at the endpoints).

First try parabolic interpolation. The derivative is linear (`y' = A (2x-1)/2 + B 2x + C (2x+1)/2)`). If the signs of the derivative at -1 and +1 are the same, you are done. Otherwise, use the solution of 3. @sds.

Answer (score 0):

how about just finding the midpoint between the appropriate two points?

given i as input between -1 and 1:

```
if i < 0 then point.x = (a.x+b.x)/2 and point.y = (a.y+b.y)/2
if i > 0 then point.x = (b.x+c.x)/2 and point.y = (b.y+c.y)/2
```